# Error On Shutdown - cmd.exe Application Error 0xc0000142

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, shutdown

I realize this question is quite common, but I can't seem to find a situation that matches exactly what my issue is, it happens at shutdown and with cmd.exe.

So recently I've been getting this bug... I may be wrong, but, I believe it appeared after I tried to cache my HDD with an msata SSD (mounted on my Z77X motherboard) and failed because I found out you can't cache the HDD and SSD unless you reinstall windows, otherwise I'd have to go through some more complicated steps. I gave up and returned the small SSD.

What's going on?:
So basically whenever I turn off the computer I get this little window that opens up called "cmd.exe - Application Error" and in the window it says "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application."

After this message shows up, it goes away after a few seconds (usually) and then the computer turns off like it usually does. I don't know if this is actually affecting anything, but I'm not sure why it's happening so I'd like to know, thanks for the help guys.

[image: cmd.exe Error]

[image]

I'm not very familiar with the event viewer, but I did look around the application problems and I couldn't find anything to do with cmd.exe and also when I did the sfc/scannow, no violations were found.

[image]
This screenshot is right after restarting the computer (and getting the error) I find no warnings/errors in the applications log.

After shutting the computer down in safe mode, I do not get the error message. But when I go back to shut it down normally, it does display the error.

Comment: Does anything relevant to cmd.exe show up in the Event Log around the time that you shutdown? Also, are any errors present when you run `sfc /scannow` in an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Under the `Windows Logs` portion in the left-hand navigation bar, click `Application`. From there, use the time stamps under the `Date and Time` column and scroll to around the time that you shut your computer off. You're looking for an entry that either says `Warning`, `Critical`, or `Error` on the left hand side that occurred right around the time you started a shutdown.

On a slightly separate note, if you boot into Safe Mode and then restart or shutdown your computer, does the same error pop-up?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem plagued me but I knew it wasn't a virus when I wiped machine clean and did a fresh install of Windows / drivers etc. and the problem returned.  I have found a solution though.

If you have an NVIDIA graphics card, uninstall Geforce Experience then the problem will go away.

Comment: So it isn't just me. I've disabled java update and adobe updates last night but during that shutdown, I still got the error. Let's hope it isn't happening today.

Comment: I confirm that uninstalling  Geforce Experience did the work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently having the same exact issue. I also have a Z77X motherboard and an OCZ vertex 4 SSD. I began having this issue after installing some drivers today on a fresh copy of Windows 7 because my system files got corrupted from an improper shutdown.

I troubleshooted this issue by performing a clean startup by going into `msconfig` and disabling everything and then re-enabling programs one by one to see what the cause was.

This issue just stopped randomly while I was running the tests and the program that seemed to be causing the issue was the Java update. I have shut down my computer several times after this and the error has not returned.